# NGINX with Tomcat configuration

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, nginx, application-server

I am new to Nginx and I need your help,

According to many forums I understood that all our static pages are stored in Nginx. When there is request comes I have to pass that request to tomcat for data and after response from tomcat response generated.

Currently, I have just done that I request directly passed to tomcat and respond to request. but I think that is not solution for performance.

So anyone can Help me?

Comment: This is well covered in http://serverfault.com/questions/293348/configure-nginx-for-jboss-tomcat

Comment: i referred it first but can not get it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can using proxy_pass mapping to your tomcat server port, for example : if your tomcat port is 8080, your conf/nginx.conf should be configured like this:

```
...
http {
    ...

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

restart it sbin/nginx -s reload, then when you can access `http://127.0.0.1`, the request forward to tomcat.

Configuration file is placed commonly under:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: hey jason thnx for reply, any change I have to do in server.xml file?

Comment: You do not have to change server.xml.

Comment: hey Jason thnx for reply, but there is one problem, solution given by you works fine but the action is not fired...

Comment: so what I have to do for that?

Comment: hey Jason thnx for reply, but there is one problem, solution given by you works fine but the action is not fired... what I mean to say is whatever action fired in those are not getting response or everytime it come to login page.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, If request already forward to tomcat, you should focus your web server code. 1 IF request not response,check tomcat status. 2 When it come to login page everytime, check your code if any filter works.

Comment: ok ok, every time when I trying to login into application it will redirect to login page only.. and let me check my code first

Comment: in root attribute, is it needed absolute path or relative path?

Comment: where I have to put my static resources for NGINX and for that all configuration code?