# Making Struts2 redirectAction use relative paths instead of absolute paths

Tags: java, struts2, nginx

I have a struts2 web application module that is running behind nginx. The application is running in a private network, but our client requested access through the internet, and so a port for it was opened.

My problem is the following. I have some actions that are executed, and then forwarded to another standard answer action using redirectAction. This was done in this way to have a single action to code a standard answer in json. Unfortunately, the location in the response header of the redirected action has the port cleaned - I guess nginx does this -, and so the redirect misses because it lacks the port.

My nginx administrator says that he cannot touch nginx redirectioning for a specific module, that it's either all or nothing.

Does anyone know if there's a way to make struts redirectAction to work on a relative path, instead of an absolute one? My only guess, and what I will be trying, is to create my custom variation of the redirectAction implementation - org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult -, but I want to know if there's a simpler way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt to generate a custom redirect action failed because of nginx, and so despite initial problems at re-configuring nginx, we ended up there because we simply couldn't solve it anywhere else.

What we found in nginx was that it had this for our module:

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Causing all redirect actions from an action based on port 8889 to drop their port (the link in location).

We found two ways of solving this: either by removing the three configuration lines above, or by adding to them this one:

```
proxy_set_header        Host            $host:8889;
```

Both solutions worked for us.

As for my attempt to create a custom action that was relative, in the end the action was formatted using the HttpServlet result object's:

```
finalLocation = response.encodeRedirectURL(tmpLocation.toString());
```

And the output, even when tmpLocation was added as relative, would end up being built as an absolute location in the action's answer. And portless.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening a particular port for tomcat, the requests for a particular domain should be forwarded internally to tomcat running at other port.

Our server has this configuration for apache infront of tomcat, we used `mod_jk` & `mod_proxy` for this purpose.

Googling these topics will describe further on how to attain this. Since they are fairly large topics in themselves.

Possible Solutions :

[Nginx reverse proxy for tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936753/nginx-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat)

[NGINX with Tomcat configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410527/nginx-with-tomcat-configuration)

Comment: Yes, nginx routes a port to Tomcat's regular port (8889 to 8081), as you describe. In the end, though, the whole issue resulted in a strange nginx configuration of the module. We are trying to understand now why the module was configured like that in the first place.